# MySQL: Prepared Statements with cross-table SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, sql-insert

I am trying to insert values into a MySQL database. I might do something like:

```
INSERT INTO `records` (`id`, `name`, `town`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

and then use prepared statements to fill in the respective value (which would be coming from user input).

Now, however, let's say I want to draw a value from *another* table in the same database... completely independently of the user. For example, let's say that the `town` is stored someplace else...

```
INSERT INTO `records` (`id`, `name`, `town`)
VALUES (?, ?, SELECT `town` FROM `otherTable` WHERE `someColumb`=1)
```

Where now only `id` and `name` are being provided by PHP prepared statements.

I saw some posts about using `SELECT` and `UNION ALL`, but I wasn't able to properly implement it (this didn't work, either):

```
INSERT into `records`
(`period`, `fullname`, `username`, `inout`, `outWhere`)
"SELECT `value` from `settings` WHERE `name`='CURRENT_PERIOD', ?, ?, ?, ?
```

where I want to auto-fill the first value `period`, but the last four should come from the prepared statement.

Thank you very much - I'm still learning MySQL syntax.

Comment: I'm not sure where the problem is. You simply write your SQL query as you'd normally write it, then you replace all user-supplied data parts with `?` placeholders and those values you feed in via prepared statements instead. Prepared statements don't care how complex the query is overall or whether there's more than one table involved.

Comment: That's what I thought... but the last statement doesn't work.

Comment: The last statement is missing the `VALUES` keyword and parentheses around the values.

Comment: I withdrew my earlier answer after rereading the manual page. But for heavens sake, get the errors (as per http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error-list.php) and look them over!

Comment: good advice; will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"INSERT into `records`
(`period`, `fullname`, `username`, `inout`, `outWhere`)
SELECT `value`, ?, ?, ?, ? from `settings` WHERE `name`= ?";
```

Then bind the params with [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Answer (score 1):

OP here... while the accepted answer is better, I just wanted to record my findings here:

The following should work to "join" multiple tables together:

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.*, ?, ?, ?
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.col1="something" AND table2.col2="anotherthing";
```

This statement can then be used with a prepared `INSERT`.